# how can i start mipmap technic from character?

Tags: opengl, c++, mipmaps

hi how can i start mipmap technic from character ? i mean example like this picture : [image]

in my code mipmap starts from camera(Near Clipping Plane). i dont want this.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,img2->w,img2->h,0,GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8,img2->pixels);

glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
```

can i make it with use these :
GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL
GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL

?
sorry for bad english :) please help me

Comment: Are you describing something like a depth of field effect, where you use smaller mipmap levels both in the far background (where they're normally used to reduce aliasing), AND in the close foreground (where normally we'd use more detailed mips), in order to concentrate texture detail on the focal plane somewhere in-between? And may I ask...why? This is an odd use of mipmaps, which might be served better by other techniques.

Comment: thank you for answer. i wanted awkward thing i know after i thought it was really absurd. And i found a way accidentally. it's name is anisotropic filtering and now my project looking so much better before. for anisotropic filtering i added these: GLfloat fLargest;
    glGetFloatv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, &fLargest);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, fLargest);

Comment: Would you like to edit your question to describe what you were looking for in more detail, now that you've found it? Then you can post an Answer with the solution you've found.